# Another Earth confusion with man's family

Tags: another-earth

I am a bit confused with this story. I enjoyed it, no doubt but what I don't understand is; Why would John (who lost his family) go to Earth Two when his other self is alive and well with his own family? He'll still be alone because the other family is unharmed.

And the ending! Why did it have to end like that?

Answer (score 1):

### Is there another John?

Yes, almost certainly. We see from the final scene that Rhoda-2 wasn't involved in the same accident that killed John's family. I think we can reasonably assume that this means that John's doppelganger will be alive on the other Earth.

The reality is that by the time John leaves Earth (courtesy of Rhoda's ticket and recommendation) he's finally come to terms with the accident. He's begun a relationship with Rhoda that may or may not last but at least he's no longer wallowing in grief for his lost family.

Seeing his alternate son and wife living a happy life without him may be a heart-breaker but it's surely a comfort to know that they're there *even if he can't be with them*.

### Why did it end that way?

It was left deliberately ambiguous. In the [words](http://filmschoolrejects.com/features/interview-director-mike-cahill-discusses-his-sci-fi-drama-another-earth.php) of Writer/Director Mike Cahill;

> **Q** : *Are you enjoying giving non-answers to questions about the film?*
>
> **MC :** *Some of them I don’t [answer]. **The meaning of the ending I try to avoid, because I feel that steals a part of the experience for
>   the audience.** I find that a lot of people have different
>   interpretations, which I encourage and think is beautiful. Like if I
>   were watching the film, I would want that experience of getting to
>   guess.*